# Set a selected value by default in List SelectList

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to set a selected value in my select list by default.

Here I have this select list :

```html
@{
List
<SelectListItem>
dateEcheancierCc = new List
<SelectListItem>
();
foreach (var dateEch in arrayDateEcheancierCc)
{
dateEcheancierCc.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = dateEch, Value = dateEch },"Value","Text","Selected-value-by-default");
}
<div class="md-select px-0" style="min-width:0px">
   @Html.DropDownList("DateEche", dateEcheancierCc, new { @class = "form-conrol" })
</div>
}
```

Here I'am trying to set "Selected-value-by-default" is selected by default but it is not working for me why ?

Here the Dropdownlist:

```html
 @Html.DropDownList("DateEche", dateEcheancierCc, new { @class = "form-conrol" })
```

Comment: Sounds like you're assigning `SelectListItem` in wrong way. You should use if-condition and then use `Selected = true` for selected value.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto didn't understand u can you please write an answer with code

Comment: @mecabmecaba is "Selected-value-by-default" an item in your 'arrayDateEcheancierCc'  ?

Comment: @Anoos yes it is an item in my array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your DropdownList as below,

```
<div class="md-select px-0" style="min-width:0px">
   @Html.DropDownList("DateEche",new SelectList(dateEcheancierCc,"Value","Text","Selected-value-by-default"), new { @class = "form-conrol" })
</div>
```

and selectList as

```
foreach (var dateEch in arrayDateEcheancierCc)
{
dateEcheancierCc.Add(
            new SelectListItem() { Text = dateEch, Value = dateEch }

            );
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/RFgoD1

Comment: it is not working for me the first option is selected by default

Comment: @mecabmecaba have you changed both your selectlist and Dropdown list?

Comment: @mecabmecaba I have tried with this list  string[] arrayDateEcheancierCc=new[]{"abc","def","ghi","Selected-value-by-default"};  and its working

Comment: my problem that i have a local variable named selected and it is an element in the array but in dropdownlist when i add selected value without " " it is not working but when i write a value of opton directly like "-- / -- / ---- " it is working

Answer (score 1):

```
dateEcheancierCc.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = dateEch, Value = dateEch },"Value","Text","Selected-value-by-default");
```

change to like this

```
dateEcheancierCc.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = dateEch, Value = dateEch, Selected = true });
```

make sure the item that you set "Selected = true" is the only one in list

I don't know your rule but you can try like this

for example : I have an array { "Jeffrey", "John", "Joe", "Josh" }, and I want set Jeffrey as default selected

```
if (dateEch == "Jeffrey")
    dateEcheancierCc.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = dateEch, Value = dateEch, Selected = true });
else
    dateEcheancierCc.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = dateEch, Value = dateEch });
```

Comment: it is a foreach here loop

Comment: how do you know which is to set selected?

Answer (score 0):

if your views have model then you can use like this

```
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedId, new SelectList(Model.SelectCollections, "Value", "Text", Model.ValueToBeSelectedInCollection))
```

Comment: i don't have selected value in my model

Comment: Your model have 
List<SelectListItems> and SelectListItems have objects like this
new { Value = 1, Text = "a" }
new { Value = 2, Text = "b" }
new { Value = 3, Text = "c" }

and you want to set SelectId = 2 Then this will selected

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Selected=true` while building the `SelectListItem`.

```
foreach (var dateEch in arrayDateEcheancierCc)
{
dateEcheancierCc.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = dateEch, Value = dateEch ,Selected = true });
}
```